# Inject host component in directive (material)

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am able to inject a component in a directive constructor like this :

```
constructor(private hello: HelloComponent) {
  console.log(hello.test)
}
```

This work nice but my directive need to work specially with Mat-Select, so I am trying something like that :

```
constructor(private matSelect: MatSelect) {
  console.log(matSelect)
}
```

this way is not working :

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[SelectSearchDirective -> MatSelect]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[SelectSearchDirective -> MatSelect]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for MatSelect!
```

Is there a way to access to MatSelect (I need to play with [(value)])

Thanks in advance.

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-tooltip-select-search?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1):

to access all the properties on the mat select you need to do
`import {MatSelect} from '@angular/material';`
then in component,
`@ViewChild('myTemplateReference') select: MatSelect;`

on the html you just need to add template reference

```
 <mat-select #myTemplateReference [(ngModel)]="value">
```

with all that, the `select` property now gives you all methods and properties of mat select.

but if all you need is the value,why not just use `[(ngModel)]="value"`

then on selection change use `(selectionChange)="doSomething()"`

```
doSomething(){

    this.value...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have access to it using `ElementRef`.

Inject `ElementRef` in your Directive as a dependency:

```
import { ..., ElementRef, ... } from '@angular/core';
...
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
```

You can now use `this.el` in your directive to have access to the MatSelect.

Comment: @Leix, were you able to fix your issue following this answer?